# Efficient method to group multiple objects by object property

Tags: javascript, algorithm

what is the most efficient way to group by multiple object properties? It groups by `category` and then by `group`.

I have detailed my implementation using a single array reduce which I will push into an array (expected output). I am not sure how to conditionally push to `sources` array which is created within the reduce.

Without using lodash groupBy or third party. I was also thinking of filtering by a key I create e.g.

`` const key = `${category}-${group}`; ``

```
const items = [
    {
        "name": "Halloumi",
        "group": "Cheese",
        "category": "Dairy"
    },
    {
        "name": "Mozzarella",
        "group": "Cheese",
        "category": "Dairy"
    }
];


// my current implementation
  const groupedItems = items.reduce((map, item) => {
    const { category, name, group } = item;

    if (map.has(category)) {
      map.get(category).push({
        name,
        group,
      });
    } else {
      map.set(category, [
        {
          name,
          group,
        },
      ]);
    }

    return map;
  }, new Map());

  console.log(Object.fromEntries(groupedItems));

// Another attempt
  const groupedItems2 = items.reduce((map, item) => {
    const { category, group, name } = item;

    acc[category] = acc[category] || { category, themes: [] };

    const source = {
      id,
      name
    };

    const totalSources = [source].length;
    const uniqueSources = [...new Set([source])].length;

    acc[category].themes.push({
      theme,
      totalSources,
      uniqueSources,
      sources: [source],
    });

    return acc;

    return map;
  }, {});

  console.log(Object.entries(groupedItems2));


// expected output

[
    {
      "category": "Dairy",
      "groups": [
        {
          "group": "Cheese",
          "totalSources": 2,
          "sources": [
            {
                "name": "Halloumi"
            },
            {
                "name": "Mozzarella"
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
]
```

Comment: This already is the most efficient method, except you should put the `item` itself instead of `{name, id}`

Comment: it does not handle the grouped sources, which is nested

Comment: You need to nest groups and sources as maps into the category map respectively

Comment: Using `Map.has()` indicates, you will get key value pairs when you dump it. However, in your expected output, there are arrays instead of objects

Comment: Sorry, I need to push to `sources` array if it has the same `group`

Comment: I added another attempt under // Another attempt

Comment: Please check `// Another attempt`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a two-level map.

There are many ways to do that. Here is one:

```js
const items = [{"name": "Halloumi","group": "Cheese","category": "Dairy"},{"name": "Mozzarella","group": "Cheese","category": "Dairy"}];

const dict = {};
for (const {name, group, category} of items) {
    ((dict[category] ??= {})[group] ??= []).push({name});
}
const categories = Object.entries(dict).map(([category, groups]) => ({
    category,
    groups: Object.entries(groups).map(([group, sources]) => ({
        group,
        totalSources: sources.length,
        sources
    }))
}));

console.log(categories);
```

Answer (score 0):

I was interested in a more generic approach to this problem.  It might or might not be useful for you, but I think it offers another way to think about such problems.  The idea is that we have a function which takes a configuration like this:

```js
const config = {
  prop: 'category',
  childName: 'groups',
  children: {
    prop: 'group',
    childName: 'sources',
    totalName: 'totalSources',
    children: {prop: 'name'}
  }
}
```

It returns a new function which takes an array of flat objects and nests them, giving totals, and changing property names as necessary.  Here is an implementation, tested only on this problem (with substantially more data added to test various scenarios):

```js
const regroup = ({prop, newName = prop, childName, totalName, children}) => (xs) =>
  childName && children
    ? Object .entries (groupBy (x => x [prop]) (xs))
        .map (([k, vs]) => [k, vs .map (omit ([prop]))])
        .map (([k, vs, kids = regroup (children) (vs)]) => ({
          [newName]: k,
          ... (totalName ? {[totalName]: kids .length} : {}),
          [childName]: kids
        })
      )
  : prop && newName
    ? xs .map (({[prop]: n, ...rest}) => ({[newName]: n, ...rest}))
  : [ ...xs]

const groupBy = (fn, k) => (xs) => xs .reduce (
  (a, x) => ((k = fn (x)), (a [k] = a [k] || []), (a [k] .push (x)), a)
  , {}
)

const omit = (names) => (o) => Object .fromEntries (
  Object .entries (o) .filter (([k, v]) => ! names.includes (k))
)  


const config = {
  prop: 'category',
  childName: 'groups',
  children: {
    prop: 'group',
    childName: 'sources',
    totalName: 'totalSources',
    children: {prop: 'name'}
  }
}

const groupFoods = regroup (config)

const items = [{name: "Halloumi", group: "Cheese", category: "Dairy"}, {name: "Mozzarella", group: "Cheese", category: "Dairy"}, {name: "Whole", group: "Milk", category: "Dairy"}, {name: "Skim", group: "Milk", category: "Dairy"}, {name: "Potatos", group: "Root", category: "Vegetable"}, {name: "Turnips", group: "Root", category: "Vegetable"}, {name: "Strawberry", group: "Berry", category: "Fruit"}, {name: "Baguette", group: "Yeast", category: "Bread"}]

console .log (JSON.stringify (groupFoods (items), null, 4))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100% !important; top: 0}
```

Note the two helper functions.  `omit` clones an object removing certain property names.  So, for instance, `omit ([age, id]) ({id: 101, first: 'Fred', last: 'Flintstone', age: 27})` returns `{first: 'Fred', last: 'Flintstone'}`  `groupBy` accepts a function which returns a key value for a value, and returns a function which takes an array of values, and returns an object with the keys found, assbociated with an array of values that generate that key.  For instance, `groupBy (n => n % 10) ([1, 3, 4, 21, 501, 23, 43, 25, 64]) //=> {"1": [1, 21, 501], "3": [3, 23, 43], "4": [4, 64], "5": [25]}`.  These are genuinely reusable functions that you might keep in your personal utility library.

The main function simply builds our output using the configuration values supplied.  If we need to nest, then we recur on the `children` node of the configuration.